# Capture response when a service returns a 500 error using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I'm getting data from a 3rd party web service using REST (using `WebHttpBinding` and `WebHttpBehavior`).  When I pass an invalid parameter in the querystring, the service responds with a 500 status and describes the problem.  The response looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2011 16:12:48 GMT
... more headers

<Error>Invalid integer value for ID</Error>
```

I would really like to be able to capture that error message. My WCF client looks like this:

```
public class DataClient : ClientBase<IDataClient>, IDataClient
{
    public DataClient (string endpointAddress)
        : base(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    }

    public string GetData(string id)
    {
        // This is where the exception is thrown
        return base.Channel.GetData(id);
    }
}
```

When I catch the exception that is thrown, that data is nowhere to be found.  It just says, "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Internal Server Error".

I tried creating a custom behavior and added a message inspector, but my custom message inspector code doesn't get executed before the exception is thrown (it does get executed if no exception is thrown).

Comment: Do you have `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>` added in the web.config of the service web dir?

Comment: I am just the client consuming someone else's service.  I don't have control over the service.

Comment: You'll have to contact whoever is providing this service and ask how to get detailed exception information.

Comment: He is already passing the information that I want.  I just want to know, "Invalid integer value for ID"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Creating a custom behavior and adding a message inspector is the way that I needed to do it.  I just needed to add my custom behavior before the `WebHttpBehavior`.  Then I can look at the whole response and throw my own exception with all the data in it!

Comment: What do you mean by adding your custom beahvior *before* the WebHttpBehavior ?

Comment: Actually you can add your custom behaviour after the WebHttpBehavior if you enable FaultExceptionEnabled on the WebHttpBehavior.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't get my test project to actually send the HTTP 500, only seems to do that when I don't want it to ;-)

In the off-chance that this will help you, try wrapping you client service call and inspect the `response` in the debugger to see if it contains the error string you are trying to capture.

```
    using (new OperationContextScope(service1.InnerChannel))
    {
        try
        {
            result = service1.GetData("5");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.ToString();
        }
        HttpResponseMessageProperty response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)
            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
    }
```

Comment: I realise this is a 11 year old answer, but this was the most elegant solution for me, and able to slot nicely right into my existing code.